# Error Importing Pyenchant in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenchant

I was able to install pyenchant, using `pip install pyenchant` and `brew install enchant`. However, when I go to import enchant, I get the following error:

```
>>> import enchant
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import enchant
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/enchant/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from enchant import _enchant as _e
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/enchant/_enchant.py", line 121, in <module>
    prefix_dir.contents = c_char_p(e_dir)
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this on Linux (*can't test on OS X I'm afraid*). If I was to hazard a guess I"d say the installation of pyenchant did not compile/link correctly against enchant

Comment: I tried uninstalling, and reinstalling enchant before pyenchant, but no luck

Comment: I get the same error from pyenchant installed using `pip3 install pyenchant` on a Mac.

Comment: I get the same error on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

In this other post ([Pyenchant utils loading error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053106/pyenchant-utils-loading-error)), they suggested to install the C library in MacOS with homebrew (brew install enchant), for me it worked.

Answer (score 0):

in python 3 64 bit enchant doesn't exist its an old issue don't know why not getting resolved if its absolute required use python 32 bit that will solve it, it works fine.