# Pyenchant utils loading error

Tags: python, pyenchant

I am trying to load pyenchant for some text processing, but after using `pip install pyenchant` when I attempt to import pyenchant I get the following error.  Has anyone seen this before or know how to solve it?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-fd4a8a7f6802> in <module>()
  1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import enchant as ench
  3 
  4 List_v1 = pd.read_csv("List_v1.txt",sep='\t')
  5 List_v1 = List_v1.fillna(0)

/__init__.py in         <module>()
 90 
 91 try:
---> 92     from enchant import _enchant as _e
 93 except ImportError:
 94     if not os.environ.get("PYENCHANT_IGNORE_MISSING_LIB",False):

/enchant/_enchant.py in <module>()
 53 from ctypes.util import find_library
 54 
---> 55 from enchant import utils
 56 from enchant.errors import *
 57 from enchant.utils import unicode

ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error. What solved my problem was to install the C library enchant which pyenchant is based off of. (See [Cannot install pyenchant on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683181/cannot-install-pyenchant-on-osx)) 
You can install it by running:

```
brew install enchant
```